# Need to enable ALX network adapter module in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, kernel, ethernet

Somehow I got stuck with an installation where ALX networking driver module is disabled, so I don't have internet access on the box. If I try to launch a new installation, immediately network adapter is recognized and kernel module listed for this adapter is ALX.

I have kernel 4.4.0.146-generic installed. How can I activate the ALX network adapter module within it? PCI Id of networking card is 1969:e091, it's *Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit ethernet adapter.*

I cannot use apt on the box obviously, since there is no connectivity. I can download and install .deb packages via a flash drive using another machine though.

thanks.

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe alx && dmesg | grep alx` Please edit your post to include the result.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install the *linux-modules-**extra**-4.4.0-146-generic* package. That package actually containes the *alx* driver.